# How to prevent an object to reveal all information about itself? (like C's friend)

Tags: php, email, doctrine

here is a simple email sending system:

```
class Email
{
    private $to, $message;

    public function __construct($to, $message)
    {
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function getTo()
    {
        return $this->to;
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}

class MailSender
{
    public function send(Email $mail)
    {
        mail($mail->getTo(), '', $mail->getMessage());
    }
}

$mailSender = new MailSender();
$email = new Email('to@at.com', 'this is the message');
$email->getTo(); // should not be available!
$email->getMessage(); // should not be available!
$mailSender->send($email);
```

you can create an email and send it. But `Email` reveals a lot about itself. Actually the `getTo()` and `getMessage()` is only needed for `MailSender`, but otherwise nobody ever should use it. The real problem is, this private methods should be available for `MailSender` only, like "friends" in C.
This seems to me a tipycal smell of misengineering.